# Gstreamer filesink black screen first few seconds

Tags: gstreamer, h.264, rtp

I decode the rtp h264 stream and display it on the screen.  In a parallel thread, recording to the mp4 file is sometimes performed.  Also, during recording, I mix the sound through mp4mux into the file.  Separately, sound and video are written perfectly, but as soon as I combine this, a problem appears.  The first few seconds of the video is a black screen, but there is sound.  At the same time, sound and video are synchronous.  How to solve this problem?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Video has a higher latency than audio. That's why you get audio sooner. So you would need to trim the file afterwards if you don't want that. Or you add some logic in your code that drops all audio until the first video is decoded.